# Execute a Local File Through Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file

Ok, so first of all, I realize that executing a local file through JavaScript is not possible. Second, I realize that the ability to execute a local file from a webpage is extremely dangerous, and that this question probably looks sketchy. However, my research has shown that it is indeed possible to execute files in the local system without the user realizing using JS by calling the PHP function exec() through AJAX.

Now before I go on, let me just say that I have no intention of using this in a dangerous way. I actually need this for my senior neuroscience/computer science thesis in which I'm:

- Working with a wireless brainwave monitoring headset .
- I need to sync clicks on webpages to event markers on another computer that's monitoring the brainwaves.
- I need to do this without it bothering the user or asking for permission over and over, in the background so as not to interrupt the experiment.

I am currently planning on doing this by writing a Chrome extension which injects a script onto selected pages, selects the element I want, then runs the function on click from there using AJAX.

So here are my questions:

1. I'm not super familiar with AJAX and PHP. What is the most straightforward way to set it up so that Javascript calls a PHP file on a click event?
2. Does anyone know of a web hosting company that does not have the exec() function disabled? I know this sounds sketchy, but I really need this to complete my thesis.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you tell us what's in the local files that requires *files* be used?  There are lots of other ways to persist data on a user's machine that aren't as ... icky.

Comment: The local file I'm running is a batch file (.bat) which runs a matlab file which sends a marker over the parallel port to the computer that is collecting the brainwave data and makes a marker for the exact time

Comment: Hm.  So, I think you're out of luck here, other than your existing plan.  The browser security model is going to prevent web pages from executing local binaries and scripts -- period.  A browser plugin may be your only option, though I'm actually not sure if local execution is possible in Chrome's extension system.

Comment: Another option: Actually run the (PHP) application on the same machine as is doing the sampling.  This also avoids the whole `exec()`-on-the-host problem

Comment: Well, I figured that. I've spent a huge amount of time researching this. PHP's exec() is definitely the easiest way I've found. It might also be possible to use flash's fscommand("exec", "whatever.bat") to do this. Finally, I found a strange and obscure chrome plugin technology that can be used called NPAPI, but I don't understand enough to use it really...

Comment: Charles, how would I do this? Intriguing. My chrome plugin is going to use ajax to call a php file, and I was going to just pull it from my existing hosting (http://jenius.me, not as if that matters). Can ajax pull from the local computer? And to get PHP running, wouldn't i also have to set up a web server?

Comment: I think you might be confused about how exec works... it will allow you to execute a shell script/batch file on the SERVER where the php interpreter is located... not on the machine the user is browsing from - unless these happen to be one in the same.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to set up a web server, PHP, and possibly whatever database you've picked, though some quality hosts will let you access remotely.  There are all-in-one packages that can set everything up in just a few clicks.  By installing the PHP app locally, the app itself can actually execute the batch script on command.

Comment: @jeff: yes you would have to set up a web server locally... but you could use something like WAMP to do this pretty easily...

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thanks for clearing this up guys. I wish I could up your reputation or something for this, but I don't think I have enough privileges haha. So what I would need to do is, in the extension, call the PHP file that is running on the local server through WAMP (like http://localhost:3000/whatever.php), then it would execute the command on the local computer?

Comment: I'll test this out tomorrow. Thanks so much you guys for the help, this absolutely saved my life and my thesis! I'll report back.

Comment: Ok, so here I am, testing this out. I am not sure if my php exec file is working though, because its not doing anything. I have a wamp running on the computer, and my batch file, called 'test.bat' which just has two commands, in the public www root. This is what my php file looks like - pretty simple (http://cl.ly/5beU). But when I load the php file directly in browser, it doesn't do anything. What am I messing up here?

Comment: (talking to self here) - I think it is working, actually, the command window just doesn't pop up. I changed the function to passthru() to see the output and it is showing execution of the batch file. Now I just need to install matlab on the wamp server and make a call to it haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer keeping track of the webpage clicks should store or append the information to a file locally, and the file should be available online. E.g. store your markers to a file locally and install a webserver on the machine so the file can be found online.

Now the machine monitoring the brainwaves can grab the data by using a simple PHP script.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    $markers = 'ip.address.of.machine/markers.xml';
    $handle = fopen($markers, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
            echo $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

And if you need to incorporate this into a webpage, use Jquery's .load() function to call the script.

```
$("#markers").load("path/to/file/above.php", function(){
      //do your thing
});
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the super late response, but this is an awesome answer, and is what I have been shooting for. The problem I'm running into now is that I am writing a google chrome extension so that I can log clicks on other peoples' websites, and when I try to make a .load() ajax request, I can't because of a security error. Do you by any chance know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

1. $.get or $ajax would be likely functions.  ex. $.get(URL, DATA, CALLBACK)  data and callback are optional, you can skip if youve got nothing to send and nothing to do on response (which sounds like it might be your case)
   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
   http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
2. Shouldn't your university be able to help you here?

Comment: For the first one, I do realize this, I was more wondering if anyone could provide a specific example of the syntax that one would use to call the PHP file... and for the 2nd, I am going to ask my university tomorrow, but I'm sure that being a university with an IT staff and a lot of importance on data security, their hosting has these dangerous functions disabled.

Comment: @Jeff, here is a correct but un-useful example of using jQuery to call a PHP script, ignoring both parameters and the response from the script: `$.get('/foo.php');`  Simple, no?  Check out the examples in the manual for things that might *slightly* more functional for you, like passing examples and doing intelligent things with the result.

Comment: Oh wow, that is simple. I actually don't need to pass any type of parameter or do anything with the results, I just need the script to run. That's really all I need? Crazy. I love jquery...

Comment: @Jeff.  thats the impression i had, that you just needed to alert the server that the event had occured.  so really the URL is the only thing you need to pass.  one note: if the exact time is important you might want to send a time stamp from the browser so that latency doesnt change the value in an unpredictable way and cause you to lose precision

Comment: Good call. How would I do this though?

Comment: $.ajax(/page.php, getTime());

Comment: Sweet, thanks so much. Super helpful. I'll up this answer as soon as I get enough reputation to! haha